# Chinese Remainder Theorem for moduli that are not necessarily pairwise coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Assume that ${n_1},\cdots ,{n_k}$ is a finite set of $k$ positive integers. We are *not* assuming that these integers are pairwise coprime. Consider the homomorphism of additive groups ${\phi}:{\bf Z}\rightarrow {{\bf Z}_{n_1}}\times \cdots \times {{\bf Z}_{n_k}}$ defined by $${\phi}(x) = (x\mod {n_1},\cdots ,x\mod{n_k}).$$
Is this mapping always surjective? If the moduli are pairwise coprime then we can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to show that it must be surjective. But is this true in general?

Answer (score 1):

No consider the map
$$\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$

Then the element $(0, 1)$ for example does not get hit.

My question to you, can you generalise this to show that the map is **never** surjective when we do not have coprimality?

> If $n, m$ are not coprime then there is some $p$ which divides both $n$ and $m$. In that case we see that there is no $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \equiv 0 \pmod n$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod m$, else $x$ would be both $0$ and $1$ modulo $p$.

Comment: If $d = {\rm gcd}({n_i},{n_j})>1$ for $i\neq{j}$ then no $k$-tuple with $0$ in the $i$-th coordinate and $1$ in the $j$-th coordinate can get hit I think!

Comment: @student Nice solution, a preimage of such an element would be both $0$ and $1$ modulo $d$, which is absurd.